# MongoDB performance, borderline of client-side & server-side, performance tips

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ionic-framework, database-design

I came across these questions when I am designing the collections for my project.

I read it from somewhere before saying that better do most of the calculation at the client side. the reason because MongoDB computation will slow down the response. But I don't really understand where is the borderline of client-side or server-side.

**Question**

1. I am writing APIs, so are the js files that are used to response the JSON is counted as client-side or server-side?
2. The ionic app typescript side is counted as client-side right?
3. The js file that use to write APIs, where will they be stored when production? at the server in MongoDB?

**Which is better in performance?**

1. Use query e.g '$gt' or '$lt' to get the filtered data from MongoDB and send the response back to the client.
2. Get the unfiltered list and filter them e.g using lodash, and send the response back to the client.

Comment: Which is better performance is not really the question here. The real indicator is that if you actually think you need to ask the question and could possibly fit your collection result in memory to be "filtered" by `lodash` or similar, then you are basically **wasting time using a database** of any kind in the first place. This is not what database engines are used for. Your primary reason for usage is that such results could not possibly be worked in memory, because that is what a database does well.

Comment: Thanks for replying, so you are suggesting to get all the filtered result in the query right?